# Steps in finding the carrying capacity K and the value of a

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I was trying to solve this for two days. how can I find the value of $K$ which is the carrying capacity and the value of a, the equation shows below.
$$
\frac{a(1-(26.273/K))}{a(1-(27.165/K))}=\frac{0.03274448}{0.03253040}
$$

Comment: Is $a$ a constant? For me, it looks like it can be cancelled away in the equation. Also, please improve the mathematical notation with MathJax so that we know what the exact details in the formula are. You mentioned that you have tried to solve it - what did you try so far? What was the result?

Comment: I have cancelled the constant a by ratio&proportion but i was stuck to get the value of K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cancelling $a$, you are left with the equation
$$\tag{1}
\frac{(1-(26.273/K))}{(1-(27.165/K))}=\frac{0.03274448}{0.03253040} = 1.0065809
$$
In order to remove numerical rounding errors, let's write this as
$$\tag{2}
\frac{1-\frac{a}{K}}{1-\frac{b}{K}}= c
$$ 
You can multiply both sides by $1-\frac{b}{K}$ to get
$$\tag{3}
1-\frac{a}{K} = c\left(1-\frac{b}{K} \right) = c - \frac{bc}{K}
$$
Let's gather terms with $K$ to the left-hand side and the terms without $K$ to the right-hand side:
$$\tag{4}
\frac{bc}{K} - \frac{a}{K} = c-1
$$
$$\tag{5}
\frac{bc-a}{K} = c-1
$$
Continuing, you can multiply both sides by $K$ to get
$$\tag{6}
bc-a = (c-1)K
$$
and now divide by $c-1$ to get the answer:
$$\tag{7}
K = \frac{bc-a}{c-1}
$$
Is it clear now?

Comment: i'm still confused. am i going to derive it then? or just distribute the value of the variables?

Comment: If there is anything unclear, please ask. I can help you.

Comment: thank you so much. this is a very big help.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark my answer as accepted, if you feel like it answers your question.

Comment: it's done. thanks again. and I hope you will answer if i have questions later on. :)

Comment: about the value of a. how should I compute it? Because I'm confused in what to do.

Comment: Ah, you mean the $a$ in the original equation? It cancels out, so the equation is valid for any value of $a$ except $0$. In other words, there's no unique solution for it. You can basically insert any value (except zero) for it.

Comment: (I understand now that I should have chosen the variable names better in my solution, because now there are two different $a$'s ...)

Comment: i tried substitute the value of K. but i'm stuck of what should I do next.

Comment: So you know the value of $K$? Wasn't this problem about solving $K$? What is the problem statement, what is it asking to do?

Comment: it is a logistic growth model problem, find the value of $a$ and $K$ . with the given equation up above.

Comment: Well, you have the value of $K$, and the value of $a$ can be anything except zero. Problem solved. Is there anything else?

Comment: okay. I have other problem. I posted it in ask questions

Comment: here's the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552298/gompertz-growth-model-problem-with-an-equation-of-p-a-ln-frackp