# Gompertz Growth Model problem with an equation of $P=a\ln(\frac{k}{P})$

Tags: calculus, mathematical-modeling

I'm having a trouble to solve the problem.
Given: $P_1=0.03274448$
$P_1=0.03253040$.
Since   $P=a\ln\frac{K}{P}$ then,
$$\frac{a\ln(\frac{K}{26.273})}{a\ln(\frac{K}{27.165})}=\frac{0.03274448}{0.03253040}$$
Find the values of $K$ and $a$

Comment: Hi again Jessabelle! What did you learn from my solution to your other problem? Notice how the $a$'s are positioned similarily in this problem. What can you conclude about the value of $a$ ?

Comment: i think $a$ is a constant number. but i'm confuse of what would i do about $a$'s  to have the value of 0.00641. i asked someone but he didn't tell me the process in how he get $a$.

Comment: Ah okay now I get it. Not only do you have 
$$\frac{a\ln(\frac{K}{26.273})}{a\ln(\frac{K}{27.165})}=\frac{0.03274448}{0.03253040}$$
but actually what you mean is
$$
\begin{cases}
a\ln \frac{K}{26.273} &= 0.03274448 \\
a \ln \frac{K}{27.165} & = 0.03253040
\end{cases}
$$
One should approach these as a system of non-linear equations.

Comment: yes it does have that. but it only have a little similarity from my previous question. 
can I solve it separately?. won't it have a different result then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with
$$
\begin{cases}
a\ln \frac{K}{26.273} &= 0.03274448 \\
a \ln \frac{K}{27.165} & = 0.03253040
\end{cases}
$$
when you consider $a\neq 0$ and divide the equations with each other, you get
$$
\frac{ \ln \frac{K}{26.273}   }{  \ln \frac{K}{27.165} } = \frac{0.03274448}{0.03253040} \approx 1.00658 = C
$$ 
(I rewrote the result of the division as constant $C$ just to simplify the following algebra.) Now it's possible to solve for $K$. Let's first use the laws of logarithms like so:
$$
\frac{ \ln \frac{K}{26.273}   }{  \ln \frac{K}{27.165} } = \frac{\ln K - \ln 26.273}{\ln K - \ln 27.165} = C
$$
now multiply both sides by the denominator, to get
$$
\ln K -  \ln{26.273} = C\left( \ln K - \ln{27.165} \right) = C \ln K - C\ln{27.165}
$$
Now let's move all the terms involving $K$ to the left side, and the terms not involving $K$ to the right side:
$$
\ln K - C \ln K= \ln 26.273 - C \ln 27.165
$$
$$
(1 - C) \ln K= \ln 26.273 - C \ln 27.165
$$
$$
 \ln K= \frac{\ln 26.273 - C \ln 27.165}{1-C}
$$
$$
K = \exp \left( \frac{\ln 26.273 - C \ln 27.165}{1-C} \right)
$$
Now you only need to plug in the known values to this expression to get the value of $K$.

How about $a$ ? Turn your attention back to the first equation, and take either the first or the second equation. You know the value of $K$, so you can easily solve for $a$ by dividing out the $\ln{}$-term.

Is it clear now? Any questions?

Comment: oh okay now I get it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have other question but I reached my limit so I cant post my question in the page.

Comment: I have other question but I reached my limit so I cant post my question in the page.
Coalition growth model "$P$=$aP^b$ 
where $aP^b$=0.03274448
$aP^b$=0.03253040
Then, $$\frac{a(26.273)^b}{a(27.165)^b}=\frac{0.03274448}{0.03253040}$$
Find the value of $a$ and $b$

Comment: @JessabelleB. In order to solve that problem, the same approach is used as in this question. Only the equation is a bit different (actually, that one is a lot easier, so the solution should be quite short). Try to solve it yourself and if you get stuck, post a new question, underlining where exactly you got stuck. I believe in you, you can do it! Just don't give up.